# When opening a infopath document, SharePoint want to use infopath instead of open document in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, open-with-explorer

You can see the message when I try to open a document :

[image: Message when attemp to open a document]

I did not change the forms before. Is it possible SharePoint updates break it ? Or something I did ?

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that your form is web browser form.
   File -> Form Options -> Compatibility.
2. Check InfoPath Forms Services, enable the following settings.

   For more information, read [Configure InfoPath Forms Services](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-infopath-forms-services-a8609546-c0d7-4956-81b6-08e93eb4b290)

   - Allow users to browser-enable form templates
   - Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users

   [image]
3. Create a simple InfoPath form and upload it to SharePoint. Check if the issue is cause by some InfoPath features that are not supported in InfoPath Forms Services.

   About InfoPath features that are supported in InfoPath Forms Services, read [Web browser compatibility in InfoPath Forms Services](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/web-browser-compatibility-in-infopath-forms-services-0356450c-82ec-40a5-b145-c7e935f73fdc).
4. Try opening form using another browser to see if it is a browser issue.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks a lot for your answer ! But unfortunately, all is set as you ask, and with an other form, or an other browser it's the same. I figured out something : forms is working well with the "Classic experience", and I have the issue only in the "new experience". So, I think the form is well. And it was working, before, with the new experience as well... :(

Comment: Does it work in IE? Try to disable browser-enable form templates rendering and re-enable them. Clear the browser cache. Re-publish the form and see if it works.

Comment: Did it. The same.
New experience : not working in any browsers.
Classic experience : working with all browsers.